# Yammer page in an iframe gives and error

Tags: yammer

"This content cannot be displayed in a frame".

Hi, I am trying to show our Yammer page within an iFrame but IE gives this error. I have added *.yammer.com to trusted sites but I still get the error. Is there a workaround?

Comment: In Chrome developer tools the network status just says canceled when it tries to get the Yammer page

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that in the trusted site, the link is https://*.yammer.com

Cheers